# Creating an X-ray vision effect on an image HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Considering HTML5/JS...

I've been trying to achieve an X-ray effect on images on mouseover.

To make it simple, there are two images stacked on top of each other.

The top image is a box and the image behind the box is a chicken.

Using a 32x32 custom mouse cursor, when user mouseover the box, inside the mouse cursor should display the image behind box (the chicken).

What I am currently doing works, it's basically a mosaic of images controlled by conditions in Javascript depending on mouse co-ordinates.

I'm am just thinking there might be some kind of library or built in function for this?

Thanks

Comment: `canvas` has some pretty powerful masking functions. Would you mind rendering onto a canvas?

Comment: yea that's what I'm going for. This was marked as dupe, but thing is, I said I need an image on top, the duplicate question shows how to draw black all over it.

Comment: From the duplicate: "On every mouse move, we clear the canvas, redraw the image, make a clipping region that is a circle cut out of a rectangle, and draw black on the entire canvas (which will draw only on the clipping region)" -- so, just draw your other image instead